# Parsing enum with EnumJsonAdapter doesn't work

Tags: json, kotlin, enums, adapter, moshi

I have a data class User :

```
 @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class User(val accountName: String,
                val gender: Gender,
                val title: Title? = null)
)
```

where gender and title must have only some values which are written in enums :

```
enum class Gender(val value: Int) {
  MALE(0), FEMALE(1), UNSPECIFIED(-1)
}

enum class Title(val value: String) {
  MRS("Mrs"), MS("Ms")
}
```

I added `EnumJsonAdapter` to moshi builder, but it doesn't work.

```
fun fromJson(json: String): User? {
      val builder = Moshi.Builder()
          .add(Title::class.java, EnumJsonAdapter.create<Title>(Title::class.java).withUnknownFallback(null))
          .add(Gender::class.java, EnumJsonAdapter.create<Gender>(Gender::class.java).withUnknownFallback(Gender.UNSPECIFIED))
          .build()
      val jsonAdapter = builder.adapter(User::class.java)

      return jsonAdapter.fromJson(json)
    }

    fun toJson(obj: User): String {
      val builder = Moshi.Builder()
          .add(Title::class.java, EnumJsonAdapter.create<Title>(Title::class.java).withUnknownFallback(null))
          .add(Gender::class.java, EnumJsonAdapter.create<Gender>(Gender::class.java).withUnknownFallback(Gender.UNSPECIFIED))
          .build()
      val jsonAdapter = builder.adapter(User::class.java).serializeNulls()

      return jsonAdapter.toJson(obj)
    }
```

I receive title = "Mr" and it is parsed as null. On gender, I get this exception :

```
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected a string but was NUMBER at path $.data.gender
        at com.squareup.moshi.adapters.EnumJsonAdapter.fromJson(EnumJsonAdapter.java:93)
```

Is it something I am doing wrong with `EnumJsonAdapter` ? So what I see, it can not be used for int, but why it doesn't work ok for title which is a String ?

If I use custom adapters for these enums everything works fine.

Comment: the enum adapter doesn't know about the inner `value` field. the enum adapter matches to the string name of the enum constant. a custom adapter sounds like the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
object NullableEnumMoshiConverter {
    fun <T : Enum<T>> create(enumType: Class<T>, defaultValue: T? = null): JsonAdapter<T> =
        EnumJsonAdapter.create(enumType)
            .withUnknownFallback(defaultValue)
            .nullSafe()
}
```

You should Add it in the builder method like this:

```
Moshi.Builder().apply {
      with(Title::class.java) {
          add(this, NullableEnumMoshiConverter.create(this))
      }
      with(Gender::class.java) {
          add(this, NullableEnumMoshiConverter.create(this))
      }
}.build()
```

Note that `withUnknownFallback(defaultValue)` does not handle the case when the JSON value is null. It addresses the issue that the value matches none of your Enum values. For example you have JSON like this

> {"title": "It"}

then the `defaultValue` value will be returned instead.

In your case, the error tells you that you should parse the Enum by name not by value. You receive a Json like that:

> {"gender": 0}

But the parser is trying to find `MALE`. Maybe you should parse the Int, and then should map it to the Enum by some method `getGenderType` like this:

```
enum class Gender(val value: Int) {
  MALE(0), FEMALE(1), UNSPECIFIED(-1)

  companion object {
            fun getGenderType(value: Int): Type = values()
                .firstOrNull { it.value == value }
                ?: throw Throwable("type:$value is not supported!")
        }
}
```